# 3D effects for hollow and solid cylinder in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, asymptote, tikz-3dplot, pst-solides3d

I want to make following things in tikz-

1. Solid Cylinder
2. Hollow Cylinder

The solid cylinder is little tilted and touching the top surface of hollow cylinder. The hollow cylinder is open from both the ends. Below is my code-

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},rotate=30]
    \coordinate (ll) at (-2,0); %lower left
    \coordinate (lr) at ( 2,0); %lower right
    \coordinate (ul) at (-2,4); %upper left
    \coordinate (ur) at ( 2,4); %upper right
    \shade [shading angle=90] (ll) arc (-180:-60:2 cm and .75cm) -- +(0,4) arc (-60:-180:2 cm and .75cm) -- cycle;
    \shade [shading angle=270] (lr) arc (0:-60:2 cm and .75cm) -- +(0,4) arc (-60:0:2 cm and .75cm) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick] (ll) arc (-180:0:2 cm and .75cm) -- (ur) arc (0:-180:2 cm and .75cm) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick, shade, shading angle=30] (ul) arc (-180:180:2 cm and .75cm);
  \end{scope}

  \fill [top color=gray!50!black,bottom color=gray!10,middle color=gray,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (0,0) circle (2cm and 0.5cm);
  \fill [left color=gray!50!black,right color=gray!50!black,middle color=gray!50,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (2,0) -- (2,-6) arc (360:180:2cm and 0.5cm) -- (-2,0) arc (180:360:2cm and 0.5cm);
  \fill [top color=gray!90!,bottom color=gray!2,middle color=gray!30,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (0,-6) circle (2cm and 0.5cm);
  \draw (-2,-6) -- (-2,0) arc (180:360:2cm and 0.5cm) -- (2,-6) ++ (-2,0) circle (2cm and 0.5cm);
  \draw [densely dashed] (-2,0) arc (180:0:2cm and 0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Below is the generated picture -

[image]

The above output is fine but it is difficult to differentiate between hollow and solid object. How to achieve it?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an elegant question. I have just added more tags including  `[asymptote]` to the question, because Asymptote seems to be an appropriate tool to draw 3 difficult kinds of cylinders: open hollow, closed hollow, and solid.

- Solid cylinder: a 3D line with thickness as 2 times of the radius of the base of the cylinder.
- Open hollow cylinder : the built-in cylinder surface in Asymptote.
- Closed hollow cylinder = Open hollow cylinder + base disk + top disk.

The surface `unitdisk` is not documented in [the Asymptote manual](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote.pdf), but it works well. It is better to run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and rotate with mouse.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,0,2,center=true,zoom=.9);
//currentlight=light(3,6,4,background=gray+opacity(0.5));

real h=2.5;
pen hollowpen=yellow+opacity(.8);
surface cyl=scale(1,1,h)*unitcylinder;
triple A=(0,0,h+1.5);
transform3 t=shift(0,3,0);
transform3 s=shift(0,-3,0);
// closed hollow cylinder
draw(t*unitdisk,hollowpen);          
draw(t*shift(0,0,h)*unitdisk,hollowpen);
draw(t*cyl,hollowpen);
label("closed hollow",t*A);

// open hollow cylinder  
draw(s*cyl,hollowpen);
label("open hollow",s*A);

// solid cylinder
real rpt=28.3464567;
pen solidpen=linewidth(2*rpt)+linecap(0)+hollowpen;
path3 c=O--(0,0,h);
draw(c,solidpen);
draw(unitcircle3,orange);
draw(shift(0,0,h)*unitcircle3,orange);
label("solid",A);

//draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--2X,Arrow3());
//draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--2Y,Arrow3());
//draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--3Z,Arrow3());
```

With `opacity(.5)`:

[image]

With `opacity(1)`, that is no transperancy:

[image]

View from above:

[image]