# Draw cylinder through points

Tags: asymptote

The unique way I know is calculation the transformation vector of the cylinder, but that is very complex and slow. Is there another way.

Currently [we](https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-core) are always drawing the cylinder around the axis X+Y. The code is the following:

```python
distance = (
    (point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2
    (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2
    (point1[2] - point2[2]) ** 2
) ** 0.5

asy += f"draw(surface(cylinder({tuple(point1)}, 1, {distance}, (1, 1, 0))), rgb(1, 1, 1));"
```

Where `point1` and `point2` are in the format `[x, y, z]`.

Edit:

I want to draw a cylinder with the center of the bottom circle in `point1` and the center of the upper circle in `point2` (like a line, but 3d-ish).
[image: image of a cylinder drawn by Mathics]
The height is the distance between the 2 points. I don't want to draw a specific cylinder, but a generic one.

Comment: I do not see clear information from your description! Could you make it more clearly? You said what are the center, the height, etc. of the cylinder? a hand-drawing may be helpful!

Comment: @BlackMild sorry for don't be clear, I have edited the question now. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: what kind of cylinder do you want to draw? open/closed hollow, or solid ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620534/140722

Comment: @BlackMild a closed cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? For open cylinder:

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,1,4,center=true,zoom=.9);
real r=1.5;
triple A=(3,2,-1), B=(2,-2,4);
dot("$A$",A,red);
dot("$B$",B,red);
real h=abs(A-B);
pen p=orange+opacity(.5);
revolution cyl=cylinder(A,r,h,B-A);
draw(surface(cyl),p);
```

For closed cylinder, just add 2 diskes

[image]

```
draw(surface(circle(A,r,normal=B-A)),p);
draw(surface(circle(B,r,normal=B-A)),p);
```

Comment: Black Mild, the PR (https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-core/pull/60) already was merged. This is fixed now! I mentioned your name in the commit message. Thanks!

Comment: @TiagoCavalcanteTrindade Nice to hear that!